# TCP/IP server code stopped working after including additional library

Tags: c++, tcp

I'm a beginner with computer-vision and networking.
I have made a program to detect and localise small marbles and that gives me the X,Y,Z position of the marble.
I have also made a small TCP/IP server application to send this X,Y,Z position to a robot.

I now want to combine these two different applications into one application.
But when I try to combine them the tcp/ip server part stops working.
After some testing with importing some different code lines I looks to go wrong whenever I try to include a different library, like OpenCV or Librealsense2. 
Would anyone know why this is happening and how I can solve this?

I've included the server code below:

```
#include <iostream>                 
#include <WS2tcpip.h>           

#pragma comment (lib, "ws2_32.lib")

using namespace std;



int main()
{

    //initialize winsock (sockets)
    WSADATA wsData;
    WORD ver = MAKEWORD(2, 2);

    int wsOk = WSAStartup(ver, &wsData);
    if (wsOk != 0)
    {
        cerr << "Can't initialize winsock! quitting" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    //create a socket
    SOCKET listening = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (listening == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        cerr << "Can't create a socket! quitting" << endl;
        return 2;
    }

    //bind the ip to a socket address and port
    sockaddr_in hint;
    hint.sin_family = AF_INET;
    hint.sin_port = htons(1701);
    hint.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = INADDR_ANY; //could also use inet_pton

    bind(listening, (sockaddr*)&hint, sizeof(hint));

    //tell winsock the socket is for listening
    listen(listening, SOMAXCONN);

    //wait for a connection
    sockaddr_in client;
    int clientSize = sizeof(client);

    SOCKET clientSocket = accept(listening, (sockaddr*)&client, &clientSize);
    if (clientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        cerr << "Socket not valid! quitting" << endl;
        return 3;
    }

    char host[NI_MAXHOST];      //client's remote name
    char service[NI_MAXSERV];   //service (i.e. port) the client is connect on

    ZeroMemory(host, NI_MAXHOST);
    ZeroMemory(service, NI_MAXSERV);

    if (getnameinfo((sockaddr*)&client, sizeof(client), host, NI_MAXHOST, service, NI_MAXSERV, 0) == 0)
    {
        cout << host << " connected on port " << service << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        inet_ntop(AF_INET, &client.sin_addr, host, NI_MAXHOST);
        cout << host << " connected on port " <<
            ntohs(client.sin_port) << endl;
    }

    //close listening socket
    closesocket(listening);

    char buf[4096];

    while (true) //this part of the code will be used to send and receive data
    {
        ZeroMemory(buf, 4096);
        float X = 12.4;
        float Y = 456;
        float Z = 900.87;

        sprintf_s(buf, "(%lf,%lf,%lf)",X,Y,Z);
        size_t buf_len = strlen(buf);

        send(clientSocket, buf, buf_len, 0);




        int bytesReceived = recv(clientSocket, buf, 4096, 0);
    }

    //close the socket(s)
    closesocket(clientSocket);

    //shutdown/cleanup winsock (sockets)
    WSACleanup();

}
```

When I add something like this, it stops working (returns error code 3):

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>       //OpenCV library onderdeel
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>         //OpenCV library onderdeel
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>      //OpenCV library onderdeel
```

Console screenshot:
[image: Console gives error 3]

Comment: *stops working* -- stops compiling or stops running?

Comment: What do you mean by `"...it stops working (returns error code 3)"`?  What returns error code 3 and what error is associated with that code?  You should also remove the `using namespace std`.

Comment: it still compiles but it stops running, I'll include a image of the console.

Comment: My guess is that the inclusion of the `opencv2` files pulls in names that clash with those of the socket api because you have `using namespace std`.  See ["Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: This did indeed solve the issue it looks like. Thank you for the tip, I will definitely read more into why "using namespace std" is bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can improve your code and solve the problem by doing these things:

1. Since you are using C++, it is much better to construct the program into several class, which means several modules, and use them to realise complex jobs.
2. It is not wise to use `using namespace std`, we will use std library only when need, such as std::cout because the std library is really huge and sometimes will be conflict with other third libiraries.
3. You can try I/O multiplexing like epoll or IOCP, they can improve the performance of your code very much.

Comment: user G.M. helped me fix it already, but thank you for your reply anyway.